# How do you change the border color for a bar chart?

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I have a pretty simple bar chart, and I tried to alter the colors based on the line-chart example from the ng2-charts website (because the bar-chart one did not have an example with custom colors), i.e., passing an array to the `[colors]` prop that looks like this:

```
public lineChartColors:Array<any> = [
  { // grey
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
  },
  { // dark grey
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
  },
  { // grey
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
  }
];
```

But the `borderColor` property seems to have no effect on bar charts.  In fact I haven't seen a border rendered yet on a bar chart actually.  Are they disabled or something for bar charts?  If not, how do you change the border color?

Also, I don't care about having individual colors for each bar.  I want them to be all the same color, it just needs to be a *certain* color.  It seems unnatural to have to pass in an array with the same color entry over and over again for each element in your chart.  Especially in a case like mine when I don't know how many entries I will have, so I have to build this array dynamically.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Try to add a demo to your question, for example by using: https://stackblitz.com/edit/line-chart-qrvv3s?file=app/app.component.ts. create your link, people can understand and use that to try to help you.

Comment: I figured out at least the first part.  `borderColor` *does* work, but you need to also set the `borderWidth` to something above 0.  This really should be mentioned in documentation.